# Как сделать паузу между циклом

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ассинхронный метод в котором идет цикл добавления в List значений. Как можно сделать так, чтоб при нажатие на кнопку цикл "замерзал" и если еще раз нажать, то он продолжался с того места где остановился

Comment: @yolosora в отличие от указанного вами вопроса, тут речь идет об асинхронном методе, потому тут, например, может также подойти taskcompletitionsource.

Answer (score 0):

[C# Mutex](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8)

я так понимаю, вам нужно смотреть в сторону Mutex, в цикл, добавить проверку WaitOne, а кнопкой замораживать, либо размораживать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, не знаю как поставить паузу в любой между всеми командами цикла (и уж тем более в теле вызываемых функций), но знаю как можно просто сделать паузу без мьютексов. Возможно это велосипед, но вот мой вариант (на псевдо шарпе):

```
bool pause = false;
Thread thread = null;

public static void Main (string[] args) {
  thread = new Thread(loop);
  thread.Start();
}

void loop () {
  for (;;) {
    // Тело цикла
    if (pause) for (;;) { 
      Thread.Sleep(15); 
      if (!pause) break; 
    }
  }
}
```

Достоинства:

- Просто реализуется

Недостатки:

- Не подходит, если нужно, чтобы цикл тормозил именно на текущей команде цикла: пауза срабатывает только если мы попадаем в её цикл.
- Выход из цикла паузы сопровождается небольшой задержкой, которая примерно равна 15 миллисекунд. Уменьшить задержку можно, но тогда и цикл паузы будет гонять в процессоре чаще. Можно вообще убрать Sleep, но боюсь, что это будет грузить систему.